# Multi Threading vs multi processing for IO bound tasks Python

Tags: python, multithreading, api, multiprocessing

I currently have 8 python files in my project  each of which perform the below listed actions,

1. 30 or more API calls, theses calls contain json payloads which read from a json file (each program has its own json file that is how I need it)
2. After the API calls are made thre results are written in specific xlsx files and txt files (1 xlsx and 1 txt for each python file, that is the requirement)

---

The advantage that I have is all the programs are independent of each other.

So I wanted to know how I can run these programs simultaneously, so that I can reduce over all execution time of the project

Currently I run each of them one by one from a parent pgm (Python pgm),sequentially by just calling them using

import pgm1.py

import pgm2.py

...

... (And so on)

My understanding is there is the subprocess module and the threading module.

I assume if i am using the threading module I would have to combine all 8 Python files into one, and make it like each python file is a function, and do the multi threading thing.

Or should I do the subprocess method where I create a 9th python file and call the other 8 as subprocess.

If there is any other way to achive the above in a simpler manner please do recommed.

I am on windows machine, I understand we can do something like

pgm1.py & pgm2.py ... Works  on bash, I cannot do that.

I need a program based solution, not a terminal based solution

Comment: you want `subprocess` here: `Popen([sys.executable, "script/number/one.py"], shell=True)`

Comment: @Aaron , thanks will try that out and update